# how to remove a screw with head broken off

Tags: removal

was working on my car's power steering and whilst screwing the fluid inlet on the head of the screw broke off. the inet hole is about an inch long and that was the part of the screw that broke. the other part of the screw is now flush with the power steering pump surface. i tried drilling it out, brazing it ( could not get the two metals to bond)  i chipped at and tried to bend the sides of the screw. next up is dremeling a slot. is there any hope for me to get this small 2 inch screw (i think #8 screw)removed from my life??

Comment: Can you post a picture, so we can see what room you are dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

There are easy out sets that  allow you to drill a pilot hole in the screw then tap in a reverse spiral tool that many times will back out a broken bolt. there have been times I had to heat the bolt quite hot with the tool in place then the bolt came out like it was never stuck. This can be the case if some put some thread locker on the bolt heat will help. [Here is a link](https://www.zoro.com/craftsman-screw-extractor-set-10pcs-9-66196/i/G3865115/?gclid=CIrBhZq2ks8CFURffgod73QD4w&gclsrc=aw.ds) so you know what I am talking about. There may be cheaper ones out there this was the first one I saw.